# Add logo to bottom right corner of a plain frame which already has an image

Tags: beamer, luatex, logos

I have a plain beamer frame with an image in it. I also want to add a logo to the bottom right corner of the frame. How do I do it?

```
\begin{frame}[plain]
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{images/someimage}
        \caption{Caption}
        \label{result:label}
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you only want it on this frame, you can use `tikz` posisioning.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[plain]
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{example-image-A}
        \caption{Caption}
        \label{result:label}
    \end{figure}
    \tikz[remember picture, overlay] {\node[anchor=south east, outer sep=0pt] at (current page.south east) {\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-B}};}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]