# Place tikz rectangle in corner of slide including infoline

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, positioning

In [Add logo to bottom right corner of a plain frame which already has an image](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/553148/add-logo-to-bottom-right-corner-of-a-plain-frame-which-already-has-an-image/553383) a way is described to put an image in the corner. However, in my theme (Madrid) there is also an infoline at the bottom. I tried adding the beamercolorbox infoline height, which is 2.25ex according to the default beamer infoline theme style file, of the infoline to my tikz placement as follows:

```
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \draw[red]  ($(current page.south east)+(-2cm, 2cm)+(0,2.25ex)$) rectangle  ($(current page.south east)+(0, 2.25ex)$);
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{frame}
```

[image: Overshoot below red box]

But it still overshoots, notice the white between the red rectangle and blue infoline. To be clear, I want there to be no white visible between the red and the blue. Is there a way to query the height of the footline in beamer? I couldn't find it in the manual. Or is there some component of beamercolorbox that makes the height somehow smaller that I am forgetting? I would be grateful for any ideas or tips!

Comment: Related: [Is there a simple command for the available height in a beamer slide?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/278429/123129)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems:

- `ex` is a font dependent unit. The footline uses `\tiny` font.
- `2.25ex` is just the height of the box, it also has a depth of `1ex`, so you need `3.25ex` in total.

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
\tiny
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \draw[red]  ($(current page.south east)+(-2cm, 2cm)+(0,3.25ex)$) rectangle  ($(current page.south east)+(0, 3.25ex)$);
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]